# Generic JSON parsing/saving to Db with Python

Tags: python, json

I need to create a generic library to parse a JSON file and insert data resulted into Database Tables

For this I need  to create a configuration file to transmit which JDO attributes will be saved in which tables

The next JSON file is an example :

```
{
"label": "first",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "john",
        "eyes": "blue",
        "books": [
            {
                "id": 999,
                "title": "the best book",
                "pages": 234,
                "pictures": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "label": "unicorn",
                        "file": "unicorn1.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "label": "frog",
                        "file": "frog3.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "title": "last book",
                "pages": 123,
                "pictures": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "label": "horse",
                        "file": "horse5.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Requirements (related to this example) :

- for each data value an iteration idx value  should be created as an id in table t_persons.idx
- "data.id" and data.name will be saved into table t_persons
- "data.eyes" will be saved in table t_eyes connected t_eyes.p_idx = t_persons.idx
- "data"."books" attributes : id, title, pages will be saved in t_books connected t_books.p_idx = t_persons.idx
- "data.books.pictures" will be saved in t_pictures connected t_pictures.b_idx = t_books.idx
- the tables are already defined and can't be modified

For a different JSON a new configuration file will be created but the python code should remain unmodified.

I've implemented a Python code to directly parse an JSON example and I've tried to generalize it.

I've saved JSON attributes in a pandas data frame corresponding to each table.

I've transformed JSON to a dictionary and I've used TOML as a configuration system.

For the JSON example I've used 3 for loops but I don't know how to specify an arbitrary number of loops inside in a generic way (the place and the number of for loops depend of the JSON structure)

Comment: Have you looked at the [JSON package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) included in the python standard library?

Comment: I know how to parse a specific JSON file. I need to create a generic library to read a JSON file.